# Describing the set of common zeros of two complex functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory

Let $f(x),g(x)$ be complex functions with infinitely many common zeros.

Is there a simple way to describe the set of their common zeros,
preferably something like $F(f(x),g(x))=0$?

If such $F$ exists, we are interested in the case where counting
the zeros $F=0$ in a region is tractable, assuming counting
the zeros of $f,g$ in a region is tractable as asked below.

As a [special case of interest](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380618/counting-base-two-probable-primes-using-real-or-complex-analysis)
take $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$ and $g(x)=\sin(\pi\frac{2^{x-1}-1}{x})$

Partial results:  over the reals we can take $f(x)^2+g(x)^2=0$
and the union of the zeros is $f(x)g(x)=0$.

Comment: Surely you don't want $f(z)\bar f(z) + g(z) \bar g(z) = 0$. So what are the restrictions on $F$?

Comment: @DieterKadelka Thanks. I edited, asking for counting the zeros of $F$.

Comment: "Complex functions" means "complex analytic", entire, or what? You can write $|f(z)|^2+|g(z)|^2=f(z)\overline{f(z)}+g(z)\overline{g(z)}=0$ for common zeros, for example.